# SQL Server special characters significance in fetch sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In the following fetch sp of sql server 2008R2, what does->  /*^*/ these characters symbolise in the column names in the select statement in @object?

```
CREATE Proc Pr_FetchPatientIssueItemsMis 
As                        
Begin                                                     
   Declare @Object varchar(MAX)                                                      
   SET NOCOUNT ON                                                       

Set @Object= '(Select '                                                       
+ 'ISD.[' + /*v*/'SalesID'/*v*/ + '] SalesID,'                                                      
+ 'ISD.[' + /*v*/'ItemID'/*v*/ + '] ItemID,'                                                      
+ 'V.DisplayName ItemName,'                                                      
+ 'V.ItemCode ItemCode,'                                                     
+ 'v.CategoryID CategoryID,'                                                      
+ 'v.Category Category'


+ ' From Dbo.[' + /*v*/'V_ItemPatientIssues'/*v*/ + ']ISD'   
+ ' Inner Join Dbo.[v_items]V ON ISD.[' + /*v*/'ItemID'/*v*/ + ']= V.ItemID'
+ ')OBJ' 

EXEC('Select * from (Select * From ' + @Object +')XYZ')                                                

Return 0                                                        
End
```

Answer (score 0):

They are in-line comments.  They don't *do* anything.  The only thing that they could symbolize would be some documentary meaning that was totally up to whoever wrote it.

My off-hand guess would be that whoever wrote this uses this procedure as a template to generate other procedures by doing searches on pairs of the `/*v*/` and replacing whatever's between them with different table/column names.